# Nodejs/Express.js path issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this Express app which makes use of routes and hbs for contemplating. When I added sub routes(like `\risi\first`) the path name for all the css/html files was appended with the route name - `risi`

How do I make them access the files?

Relevant code from app.js:

```
var risi= require('./routes/risi');
app.use('/risi', risi);
```

Risi.js route:

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('risi', { title: 'RISI' });  //Works perfectly fine
});

router.get('/first', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('risi', { title: 'RISI' }); //unable to access the CSS / JS from here
});

router.get('/second', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('risi', { title: 'Joi' });
});

router.get('/third', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('risi', { title: 'Log' });
});

router.get('/fourth', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('risi', { title: 'Yo TO RISI!! <3' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the error from console:

`GET /risi/css/main.css 404 99.4567 ms -1166`

The said CSS file is at `/css/main.css`

Someone pls hlp!

Comment: Where's the html? Is your link to the css `css/main.css` or `/css/main.css`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an absolute path

```
/css/main.css
```

(note the prepended `/`) to link to your css files to guarantee the href isn't appended to the routes href